# remove all occurences of a character in C string - Example needed

Tags: c, string

InputString:    `"I am unwell" "We need to go to the doctor" "How long will it take?"`.

OutputString: `I am unwell We need to go to the doctor How long will it take?`

The string needs to cleaned of all occurrences of the char `"` . I can think of the following approacg

1. Use, strchr() function finding first occurrence of `"`
2. Move all characters in the string left by once position.

Repeat steps 1 and 2 , until strchr() returns a NULL pointer.

I feel this is very inefficient way to approach this problem. I need to know , if there are other methods to achieve this? Pseudo code or actual code will both be appreciated.

Comment: character at a given index; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457608/how-to-remove-the-character-at-a-given-index-from-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
for (s=d=str;*d=*s;d+=(*s++!='"'));
```

Comment: @ephemient: Yeah well I want to keep it readable and instructive. ;-)

Comment: @R - could you explain how this works? I understand that a char* in c is an array of characters terminated by '\0'. You do not delete any character '"' in you for loop. Also what is the behavior of `d+=(*s++!='"')`. There is a nice little explanation below by `Leftium` , but he does not not explain what to do when the `if condition` in line 2 of his fails.

Comment: @Eternal Learner: It's safe to do the assignment even if the source points to `"`, because the destination pointer hasn't been updated and the next loop around will write over it.  `s++` post-increments `s`; `*s++` dereferences post-incremented `s`; `*s++!='"'` compares dereferenced post-incremented `s` to `"` and yields `1` or `0`; `d+=(*s++!='"')` increments `d` by one if dereferenced post-incremented `s` is not `"`.  Pretty simple.

Comment: @Eternal Learner: if the if condition fails, the current char is a ". The body of the if condition copies the char at source to destination, so this is skipped. Only the increment of source happens.

Comment: @R. - You want to keep it "readable" and yet you are relying on the integer value of `==` to do arithmetic?  It's a cool trick, but I wouldn't say it's "readable".  :-)

Comment: @asveikau: My comment about keeping it readable was halfway a joke, but I don't have a problem with using `==` in arithmetic. I do things like `(x==y)<<FLAG_BIT` or `y&-(x<y)` all the time.

Comment: I just used this to de-hyphenate a UUID. Perfect, except I had to add some parentheses around the condition to satisfy gcc. I have `for (s=d=str;(*d=*s);d+=(*s++!='-'));`The compiler error I had to resolve was this: `error: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Werror=parentheses]`.

Answer (score 9):

You can accomplish this by visiting each char of the string once. You basically copy the string over itself, skipping the " characters:

pseudocode:

1. Start with two pointers: SOURCE and DESTINATION. They both point to the first char of the string.
2. If *SOURCE == NULL set *DESTINATION = NULL. Stop.
3. If *SOURCE != " set *DESTINATION = *SOURCE and increment DESTINATION.
4. Increment SOURCE. Go to step 2.

code:

```
// assume input is a char* with "I am unwell\" \"We need to go..."

char *src, *dest;

src = dest = input;    // both pointers point to the first char of input
while(*src != '\0')    // exit loop when null terminator reached
{
    if (*src != '\"')  // if source is not a " char
    {
        *dest = *src;  // copy the char at source to destination
        dest++;        // increment destination pointer
    }
    src++;             // increment source pointer
}
*dest = '\0';          // terminate string with null terminator              

// input now contains "I am unwell We need to go..."
```

**update**: fixed some bugs in code

Comment: Actually your code has a bug. As written, it starts reading the first byte and writing the second, so it will clobber its own input. You need to increment `destination` *after* storing to it, not before, and throw out the final increment of `destination` entirely.

Comment: And `destination = NULL; // terminate string with NULL` code doesn't match comment.  `*destination = '\0'; // terminate string with NUL` would make more sense.  Also, note that `"..."` is a `const char *`, not a `char *` — as per the C specification, writing to it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @ephemient: as per the C specification, string literals are unmodifiable `char[]` (6.4.5/#6), not `char *` and much less `const char *`. *gcc's option `-Wwrite-strings` makes literal strings be of type `const char[]` and therefore makes gcc compile a language that is almost C*

Comment: You're still using `NULL` where you should be using 0 (or `'\0'` if you insist). `NULL` is a pointer constant, not the null character.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving the characters "in-place" to overwrite the character being deleted, create a new string.

This minimizes the number of characters copied by copying each valid character once.  With the original method, characters near the end of the string are copyied *n* times, where *n* is the number of invalid characters preceding it.

Comment: This is inefficient. My algorithm is in-place or out-of-place (I wrote it in-place but either works) and only copies each character once.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is not very big, the obvious answer would be to have a separate string. 
 A single loop till you get \0 (End of string)
Have a loop (Gives you O(n))  and a comparison to check if the current location of the string is the character in question (again O(n) )

In all :

---

```
  s1 = original array
  s2 = new array to store the final result
  c = character in question.  
  current_pointer = 0 
  new_pointer =0 
  while(s1[current_pointer] != '\0') {
   ele = s1[current_pointer] ;

   if( ele != c)  { 
    s2[new_pointer++] = ele
   }
    current_pointer++
  }
```

---

Note that this method works only when string sizes are small. We need to go for better methods as size of string increases.

Hope this helps.