# stripping end of a string in C

Tags: c, string, parsing, pointer-arithmetic

I need a function to remove `)` character from end of a string.
for example, `hello,world)` should be converted to `hello,world`.

I have written this :

```
char *a="hello,world)";
int a_len=strlen(a);
*(a+a_len-1)='\0';
printf("%s", a);
```

but nothing is shown in the output.

Comment: You have a nice compiler that doesn't `SIGSEGV` on this.

Comment: @devnull: Why would the compiler SIGSEGV? ;)

Comment: tried it but a_len-2 does not work too.

Comment: don't try it with a_len-2 because apparently i was wrong

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis You might want to refer to [this](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html).

Comment: @devnull: i think he meant that SIGSEGV takes place during runtime not compile time

Comment: @HayriUğurKoltuk Maybe.  I thought that _executing_ was implicit.  (on executing this)

Comment: Might be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457608/c-remove-character-from-string

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) then **use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should ideally be getting a segmentation violation runtime error.

You have assigned a pointer to a string literal which resides in read-only memory. Trying to modify that is bad!

Try copying it onto the stack

```
char a[] ="hello,world)";
```

If you really have to use dynamic memory (please write that in your question) then you have to manually copy your string there:

```
char *a = malloc(sizeof("hello,world)"));
memcpy(a, "hello,world)", sizeof("hello,world)"));
int a_len=strlen(a);
a[a_len - 1] = '\0';
```

Alternatively you can also have printf truncate your string:

```
printf("%.*s", strlen(a) - 1, a);
```

Also as Basile pointed out there is `strdup`

```
char * a = strndup("hello,world)", sizeof("hello,world)") -2);
```

Note that here we have to truncate by two characters because `sizeof` includes the null terminator, but `strndup` will always add one.

Comment: You could use `strdup`

Comment: I have to keep my code clean of libc functions, so I think memcpy is a better one to use.

Answer (score 1):

**Analysis:**

Line #1: `char *a="hello,world)";`

Variable `a` points to an array of characters, located in the (read-only) code section of the program

Line #3: `*(a+a_len-1)='\0';`

A memory access violation occurs, when the CPU attempts to write into a read-only memory section

**Solution:**

Line #1: `char a[]="hello,world)";`

Variable `a` is an array of characters located in the stack of the program, which is a read/write section

Answer (score -2):

I must use dynamic memory so I have to leave char[].

trying this also does not work:

```
char *a=malloc(4);
a="hello,world)";
int a_len=strlen(a);
*(a+a_len-2)='\0';
printf("%s", a);
```

Comment: You are again assigning a pointer to read-only memory. You have to copy the string into your dynamic memory.

Comment: also it should be -1 :)

Comment: Look my answer, I have edited it. Please use comments for discussions instead of posting your own not working answer.

Comment: Should `malloc` a bigger zone then use `strcpy`