# Deleting the previous character?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a program prints out a certain string to a text file, what i'm trying to do now is making an "if" order to delete the previous character came before another certain character, for example:

```
if(character 'a' came directly before character 'b')  \\"ab"
delete a ;
```

Sorry for my code but i really don't know how to do it.
Thank you.

Comment: do you have any other code than pseudocode to show? what have you tried already?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What didn't work?

Comment: Ok i already wrote 1575 coding line in the past 12 hours .. so don't try to make me feel guilty , if you can help just help , thank you

Comment: How is this different from replacing every `"ab"` with `"b"`?  Just use the standard search and replace idiom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string test = "asdfabasdabab";
    regex reg(".b");
    test = regex_replace(test, reg, "b");
    cout << test << endl;
}
```

or

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string test = "asdfabasdabab";
    std::regex reg("ab");
    test = regex_replace(test, reg, "b");
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
}
```

to write this string to a file add:

```
#include <fstream>

std::ofstream out("output.txt");
out << test;
out.close();
```

Comment: i'm trying to delete this character only in case it came before a not deleting it from the whole text , thank you

Comment: @user3487485 you said you need to delete character before 'b', in my example the first 'a' is not being deleted, so...

Comment: @user3487485 the output is "asdfbasdbb" - each 'a' before 'b' was deleted. What is wrong?

Comment: `_TCHAR' has not been declared

Comment: @user3487485 added simplified solution

Comment: A bit overkill:-).  But certainly the simplest solution to implement if you don't already have search and replace in your toolkit.

Comment: @JamesKanze :p OP must have been introduced to regex.

Comment: What happens if the OP has pre-C++11 and no `std::regex`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I would recommend to use atl or boost ^_^. Honestly, from the definition I didn't get what OP wants exactly to do, so I decided to introduce more general solution.

Comment: @QuéPadre If he's already familiar with `std::regex`, he probably already has a search and replace function in his tool kit:-).  (Seriously, if I didn't have such, I'd use the regex solution as well, at least in a first draft.  It's simple and effective to program, and while probably overkill for this particular problem, it still works well.)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: `boost::replace_all` :)

Answer (score 4):

You need a plan:

- to obtain the string
- to process it
- to obtain the name of the file in which to output
- to dump the string there

There are reasonable choices, to start with: hardcode the string in the program, and hardcode the name of the file as well.

So we are left with processing and dumping:

- processing: use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), look-up the `at()` method and the `erase` method (using positions, not iterators)
- dumping: use [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream), look-up its constructor (which takes a file name) and use the `<<` method to put data into it: `myfile << mystring;`

Comment: It's very, very rare that `std::string::at()` is appropriate.  Usually, a bounds error is an error, not an exception.

Comment: @JamesKanze: correctness first, performance second :)

Comment: `std::string::at()` is only correct if a bounds error is an exceptional, but correct case.  On all of the implementations I use, `std::string::operator[]` will crash on a bounds error, which is the desired behavior.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I am surprised to see *you* expect a crash on an undefined behavior operation; experience suggests that you may just read garbage...

Comment: My experience suggests that you get a crash.  At least, it's the case in debug builds with both VC++ and g++.

Answer (score 2):

Try following code:

```
for (int index = 0; arr[index] != '\0'; index++) 
{
    if(arr[index] == 'a' && (arr[index+1] == 'b')
        continue;
    //write char to file;
}
```

Comment: I'm finishing my 1575 line program and i didn't use arrays i used string in it ,this problem i'm asking for help was emergency , but thank you anyway

Comment: Prefer `std::vector` to arrays.  Also `std::string` can be indexed as if it was an array.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a simple search and replace to me: replace
`"ab"` with `"b"`.  The function I usually use for this is:

```
std::string
replaceSequence(
    std::string const& original,
    std::string const& from,
    std::string const& to )
{
    std::string results;
    std::string::const_iterator start = original.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = original.end();
    std::string::const_iterator next
        = std::search( start, end, from.begin(), from.end() );
    while ( next != end ) {
        results.append( start, next );
        results.append( to.begin(), to.end() );
        start = next + (to.end() - to.begin());
        next = std::search( start, end, from.begin(), from.end() );
    }
    results.append( start, next );
    return results;
}
```

It's a useful function to have around if you're doing much text
processing.

Answer (score -2):

may be it will help.............

```
int main(void)
{
    char* str = malloc(strlen("abcdef")+1);
    strcpy (str, "abcdef");
    removeChar (str, 'b');
    printf ("%s", str);
    free (str);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

> > acdef

Check following link

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457608/c-remove-character-from-string
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/63164-removing-character-from-string/
```

Comment: This is not incorrect code, however it is hardly idiomatic C++ code. Let's avoid crippling our public by teaching the unsafe C way before teaching the safe C++ way :x

Comment: i'm trying to delete this character only in case it came before a not deleting it from the whole text , thank you