# Removing characters in c string

Tags: c, string

How to remove a specific character from a string in c ?

Eg: if the string is "abcd"
    i need to remove the character of index 1
    then the result should be , "acd"

My attempt:

```
void removeSymbol(char *line){ 
    int i,j; char c;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(line);i++){ 
        c = *(line +i); 
        if(!(isdigit(c)||isalpha(c))){ strcpy((line+i),(line+i+1)); } 
    }
    printf("%s\n",line); 
}
```

Comment: void removeSymbol(char *line){
    int i,j;
    char c;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(line);i++){
        c = *(line +i);
        if(!(isdigit(c)||isalpha(c))){
           strcpy((line+i),(line+i+1));
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",line);
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [C remove character from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457608/c-remove-character-from-string)

Answer (score 1):

```
static inline void removeSymbol(char *line, size_t index){
    memmove(&line[index], &line[index+1], strlen(&line[index]));
    //printf("%s\n",line); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the prototype of removeSymbol API. I hope this below code will meet your requirements

```
void removeSymbol(char *line, int index)
{ 
    //Added as per comments
    if ( (index > 0 ) && ( index <= strlen (line) ) )
    {

         //index-> index which needs to be removed.
        // +1 is added in memmove last argument to move '\0' character also

        memmove (&line[index-1], line + index, strlen (line)-index +1 );
    }

}

int main(void){

    char symbol [] = "abcdefgh";
    removeSymbol (symbol, 8);
    printf ("%s\n", symbol);
}
```

Comment: I would add a check to make sure that `index` is within bounds. `0 <= index < strlen(line)`.

Comment: And I would calculate `strlen(line)` outside the function **once**, and then pass it to the function as an additional input argument.

Comment: A C programmer should count numbers from 0. `index==0` should remove the first character in `line`.

Comment: ALso it is weird that you use `&x[y]` notation for first argument to memmove and `x + y` notation for the second... be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void removSymbol(char *,int);
main()
{
    int index=1;
    removSymbol("abcd",index);
}
void removSymbol(char *line,int index)
{ 
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(line)-1;i++)
    { 
        if(i<index) 
        {
            *(line+i) = *(line +i);
        }
        else 
        {
            *(line+i) = *(line+i+1);
        }

    }
    *(line+i+1)='\0';
    printf("%s\n",line); 
}
```