# Assigning NULL to the middle of a c-string

Tags: c, string, null-terminated

I'm writing a function `eliminate(char *str, int character)` that takes a c-string and a character to eliminate as input, scans `str` for instances of `character` and replaces the value at the current index with... what? I thought `NULL`, but this seems risky and could mess with other functions that rely on the null-terminator in a c-string. For example:

```
char *eliminate(char *str, int character) {
    if (!str) return str;

    int index = 0;
    while (str[index])
       if (str[index] == character)
          str[index++] = '\0'; //THIS LINE IS IN QUESTION
    return str;
}
```

My question is, how do I properly implement this function such that I'm effectively eliminating all instances of a specified character in a string? And if a proper elimination assigns `'\0'` to the character to be replaced, how does this not affect the entire string (i.e., it effectively ends at the first `'\0'` encountered). For example, if I were to run the above function twice on the same string, the second call would only examine the string up to where the last character was replaced.

Comment: You might want to rethink this loop... seems like it'll run forever...

Comment: `NULL` is not a char and shall never be use as an integer value. Most compilers define it `(void *)0`. Enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them!

Comment: And pick one language.

Comment: @user2864740: There is no `NUL` constant and OP clearly writes `NULL`.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: That's why I asked to remove one language. Anyway, even as `NULL` is defined `0` in C++, one should not use it as integer (and not anymore as _null pointer constant_. C++11 introduced `nullptr` for good reasons)

Comment: You forgot to state your actual goal.

Comment: Do not change the your question once you got an answer which renders the answer incorrect. This is no forum. Instead, you might add a note about a correction.

Comment: Hey, this might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457608/how-to-remove-a-character-from-a-string-in-c

Comment: @MikeB: No. OP wants to replace, not remove. But it is unclear what his point is, so it might as well just be malworded.

Comment: You still do not define "properly". How do you detect the final end of the string after replacing?

Comment: @Olaf, MikeB *is* the OP. Reading the question, I understand it as he wants to remove a character. "Replacing with 0" is just bad phrasing (or, if it was intentional, a bad idea). The question he found indeed does what he asks.

Comment: @Jongware: Well, yes, I did not notice he is OP actually when I wrote the comment. However, this is completely different from what he writes in the question (and what his code implies). It cannot be **that** complicated to see a difference betwee "replace" and "remove". Point is he asks if his approach is correct, but does not provide a clear definition of "correct", i.e what he actually wants to accomplish.

Comment: @Olaf: I submit the idea that OP may have reasoned that "replacing a charcater with 0, which is not a valid character in a C string, is **thus** equal to removing it".

Comment: @Jongware: Not necessarily. He might have something in mind like `strtok`. Just replacing will make it impossible for the caller to detect the actual end of the string, unless it stores information about the original length. No problem if it ust to shorten, but indications are to the oposite.

Comment: After the last edit it indeed looks like a duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457608/how-to-remove-a-character-from-a-string-in-c and the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28609778/4023446 with `RemoveChars` was needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to use such replacement if you know what you are doing.

It can work only if the char buffer `char *str` is writable (dynamically allocated, for example by `malloc`, or just char array on stack `char str[SIZE]`). It cannot work for string literals.

The standard function `strtok` also works in this way. By the way, probably you can use `strtok` for your task if you want to have null terminated substring.

---

It does not make sense to have integer type for charcter function argument: `int character` -> `char character`

Comment: This does not always work reliable, as OP does not store further context where he actually put the terminator. It depends on context not shown.

Comment: @Olaf What is not reliable? The OP wants to replace some character by '\0'. The question is asked in the context of null terminated C string. So, I assume that the author wants to have null terminated substring marked by some delimiter. Of course, it changes the original buffer, so the buffer cannot be used as before for the initial string as with `strtok`.

Comment: Have a look at `strtok` and why it is not thread-safe. Then you might see the difference.

Comment: @Olaf I know how `strtok` works and I know about `strtok_r`. That is why I wrote in the first line that it can be done only "if you know what you are doing." It is quite safe to build such substring if the caller is able to properly free the initial string.

Comment: "if you know what you are doing" Is far too ambivalent here. Especially as OP apparently is a beginner.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, now I see it after several question editions and all those comments.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the character by '\0' will likely cause confusion. I would eliminate the undesirable character by shifting the next eligible character into its spot.

```
char *eliminate(char *str, int character) {
    if (!str) return str;

    int index = 0, shiftIndex = 0;
    while (str[index]) {
       if (str[index] == character) 
          index++;
       else {
          str[shiftIndex] = str[index];
          shiftIndex++, index++;
       }
    }
    str[shiftIndex] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```