# Error running function in C but not in C++

Tags: c

I have a piece of code that works in C++ but doesn't work in C. Confused since it seems to be written in C for the most part.

I took from a book, which checks whether two character arrays are anagrams of one another. The book is from 2005 so I think that is part of the reason why the code is more "C style" than C++. I have written a more "modern" solution as well baed on my general experience, but it could be optimised further of course.

I'm on Apple Silicon and compiling with `clang`.

The original code (I'm assuming C++03 standard):

```cpp
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>

int anagram(char *x, char *y) {
  char *p;
  if (!*x && !*y) return 1;
  p = strchr(y, *x);
  if (!p) return 0;
  *p = NULL;
  strcat(y, p+1);
  return anagram(x+1, y);
}
```

Refactored C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int anagram(char *x, char *y) {
  char *p;
  if (!*x && !*y)
    return 1;
  p = strchr(y, *x);
  if (!p)
    return 0;
  *p = 0;
  strcat(y, p + 1);
  return anagram(x + 1, y);
}
```

C equivalent(?) - fails to run : `bus error ./a.out`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int anagram(char *x, char *y) {
  char *p;
  if (!*x && !*y)
    return 1;
  p = strchr(y, *x);
  if (!p)
    return 0;
  *p = 0;
  strcat(y, p + 1);
  return anagram(x + 1, y);
}
```

C Main function

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *x = "restful";
  char *y = "esrftul";
  printf("%d\n", anagram(x, y));
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why is the C++ code relevant to this question at all? You have some C code and it fails to run. Wouldn't it be sufficient to just specify that and remove all the C++ background information?

Comment: @nimitz, Post the C code that first calls `anagram()`.  [mcve]. Bets are code is attempting to modify a _string literal_.

Comment: This code is also not a [mre] because whether you run into an error depends on the `main` function which calls this code and provides `x` and `y`.

Comment: @JanSchultke that's true, apologies. was just providing context, maybe it's due to one of the differences between the languages so I'd like that explained

Comment: Is there any difference in between original C code and "C equivalent" at the end? If not why give it twice? How this code was called?

Comment: The code is badly written and is not worth wasting your time on.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès there's no original C code, that code is what I believe to be the C equivalent of the original C++ function from the book

Comment: Updated with the C main function

Comment: @SupportUkraine it's more of a comparison between the refactored C++ (not sure why the original assigned *p to NULL instead of 0) and the last one but yeah

Comment: @nimitz Didn't you gave twice the same code? One labeled "The original code (I'm assuming C++03 standard):" the other "C equivalent(?)"?

Comment: aside from the imports they are the same, my attempt uses C++ strings so that's different, yeah.

Comment: Please make sure you turn all the compiler warning flags on! `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` it will really help.

Comment: what language does the book target actually? C++ code can look like C but still not compile as C, so what matters is whether the code was acutally meant to be compiled as C

Comment: Updated the string literals to character arrays, I don't get any warnings aside from the unused arguments in main()

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai The book title literally translates to "Programming in C/C++" so it conflates the two, given that the code sample from the book uses `#include <iostream.h>` I assume it's an older standard of C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y` is a pointer to a string literal, therefore `strcat(y` is invalid as it's modifying a const pointer. Your compiler should be [warning you](https://godbolt.org/z/91ncvxsbW) that this isn't valid:

```
<source>:18:13: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
   18 |   char *x = "restful";
      |             ^
<source>:19:13: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
   19 |   char *y = "esrftul";
      |             ^
```

Adding the relevant `const`s results in [compiler errors](https://godbolt.org/z/bW46ovjj6):

```
<source>:9:7: error: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers
    9 |   p = strchr(y, *x);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:13:3: error: no matching function for call to 'strcat'
   13 |   strcat(y, p + 1);
      |   ^~~~~~
/usr/include/string.h:130:14: note: candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('const char *') would lose const qualifier
  130 | extern char *strcat (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
      |
```

Also note that the ranges passed to `strcat` are overlapping, this is undefined behaviour and can result in either the [wrong result](https://godbolt.org/z/W9h4hnrhd) or a [crash](https://godbolt.org/z/r46nczs5W) depending on your compiler, and compiler settings. You should use `memmove` instead which allows operating on overlapping ranges:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int anagram(const char *x, char *y) {
  char *p;
  if (!*x && !*y)
    return 1;
  p = strchr(y, *x);
  if (!p)
    return 0;
  memmove(p, p + 1, strlen(p));
  return anagram(x + 1, y);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const char *x = "restful";
  char y[] = "esrftul";
  printf("%d\n", anagram(x, y));
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/48WGf5e1E

Comment: He was asking about `C` function. You compile it using C++ compiler. Error messages are not related to the `C` language.

Comment: @0___________ clang gives similar errors in c mode: https://godbolt.org/z/a51bEYdrT

Comment: That's true, it is the same in C++, I was converted strings with .data() and didn't realise

Comment: @AlanBirtles your godbolt link compiles a completely different code. The code as posted does not https://godbolt.org/z/PGo3oEKWG **do nor manipulate**

Comment: @0___________ the question was tagged with c++, if the user didn't want c++ answers they shouldn't have tagged with c++

Comment: @SupportUkraine Does concatenating y with p+1 count as overlapping? That's the only overlap I see, but his code using `memmove` to overwrite the found character with the rest of the string does work for me, unlike with `strcat`

Comment: @SupportUkraine Is it because y becomes `p+1` at some point?

Comment: Cool, thanks to both of you, as well as everyone else for the help

Comment: @SupportUkraine out of curiosity would there be some way of conditionally using `strcat` based on the pointers?

Comment: That's true, it just makes more sense in this case, simply overwriting the portion needed instead. Thanks again!

Comment: @nimitz there are various methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457608/how-to-remove-the-character-at-a-given-index-from-a-string-in-c) but `strcat` just won't work in this case, `memmove` is designed to work with overlapping ranges, it should also be marginally faster as it doesn't have to search for the null terminator in `y` (in general the c string functions are suboptimal when called repeatedly due to repeated searches for the end of the string)

Comment: Either way it is interesting that the C++ compiler still accepted and ran the first refactored version, must a difference with how strcat() is treated

Comment: @nimitz that's the joy of undefined behaviour, code can seem to work but be fundamentally broken. I strongly recommend turning on the address sanitizer as it catches a lot of (but not all) mistakes. Your c++ code still doesn't produce the correct output for me https://godbolt.org/z/dxY9K37Y5 and the sanitizer complains https://godbolt.org/z/jT3Ye8jhz

Answer (score 1):

```
  char *x = "restful";
  char *y = "esrftul";
```

`x` & `y` reference string literals. Any attempt to modify string literal invokes undefined behaviour. This undefined behaviour in your case is causing "bus error"

Also `strcat(y, p + 1);` requires to `y` to be long enough to accommodate the concatenated string.

You need to define both as `char` arrays and `y` has to be long enough.

```
  char x[] = "restful";
  char y[128] = "esrftul";
```

I did not analyze your code deep enough to provide minimum required `y` array length

https://godbolt.org/z/K3Y99rbTn

Comment: Thanks, I confused string literals with character arrays. However even assigning length 128 to y it still fails with "trace trap"

Comment: @nimitz it has to be long enough. 128 might not be long enough

Comment: @nimitz looks like it ends up with overlapping `strcat` ranges: https://godbolt.org/z/r46nczs5W