# Converting ISBN strings to numbers

Tags: c, while-loop

This code removes (ignores) the "`-`" from a string, but only one time.
How can I reset the `*p` to let it do the loop again, after I changed my ISBN string?

```
char ISBN[] = "3-423-62167-2";
char *p = ISBN;
while (*p)
{
    if (isdigit(*p))
    {
        const char digit = *p - '0';
        num = (num * 10) + digit;
    }
    ++p;
}

//New char ISBN[] = "3-446-19313-8" and start from beginning
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9895216

Comment: Wrap the code as a function: `int strtoisbn(char const *str) { int isbn = 0; unsigned char c; while ((c = *str++) != '\0') { if (isdigit(c)) isbn = isbn * 10 + (c - '0'); } return isbn; }`.  Then use it: `int isbn1 = strtoisbn("3-423-62167-2"); int isbn2 = strtoisbn("3-446-19313-8");`  You may need to worry about the use of `int` as the data type (especially for 13-digit ISBNs); you might well need `long long` or `int64_t`.  You may also have to worry about the `X` check digit for 10-digit ISBNs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I think your x-ref is dealing with a different problem altogether.  I can see the superficial relationship, but I believe this is about reusing the code fragment to convert two ISBN numbers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I will defer to your psychic debugger skills.

Comment: New `char ISBN[]` will be in a different memory location, assign its address to `p` then you can start from the beginning of the new memory location.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the code as a function:

```
int strtoisbn(char const *str)
{
    int isbn = 0;
    unsigned char c;
    while ((c = *str++) != '\0')
    {
        if (isdigit(c))
            isbn = isbn * 10 + (c - '0');
    }
    return isbn;
}
```

Then use it:

```
int isbn1 = strtoisbn("3-423-62167-2");
int isbn2 = strtoisbn("3-446-19313-8");
```

You need to worry about the use of `int` as the data type (especially for 13-digit ISBNs); you might well need `long long` or `int64_t` or an unsigned variant of those. You also have to worry about the `X` check digit for 10-digit [ISBN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number)s; these are not a factor in 13-digit ISBNs.

If you can't write functions yet, then (a) learn how to, and (b) reinitialize `p` to point to the new ISBN:

```
p = ISBN2;
```

and then run the same code again.  But writing the same code twice is an indication that you probably need to write a function to do the job.