# Erase blank spaces between string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, space

So, I am trying to remove the blanks spaces from a sting input by the user. I already have an option where the program counts the vowels and inverts the string. The one where I need help starts with //espaços. What I did was something like: if the "palavra" string, the original one, has a space (`' '`) in any position, the new string with no space will have the next char from the string "palavra" in that position:

```
/*palavra = " o  l  a  _  o  l  a"
             [0][1][2][3][4][5][6]
  palavra3 = "o  l  a  o  l  a"
             [0][1][2][3][4][5]*/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(void) {
    char palavra[10];
    char palavra2[10];
    char palavra3[10];
    int i;
    int vogais = 0;
    int j;
    int k;
    int espaco = 0;

    printf("Introduza uma string: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", palavra);

    //vogais
    for (i = 0; palavra[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (palavra[i] == 'a' || palavra[i] == 'e' || palavra[i] == 'i' ||
            palavra[i] == 'o' || palavra[i] == 'u' ||
            palavra[i] == 'A' || palavra[i] == 'E' || palavra[i] == 'I' ||
            palavra[i] == 'O' || palavra[i] == 'U')
            vogais ++;
        // else
        //     printf("");
    }

    printf("Vogais: %i", vogais);

    //invertida
    for (i = 0; palavra[i] != '\0'; i++);
    {
        k = i-1;
    }
    for (j = 0; j <= i-1; j++) {
        palavra2[j] = palavra[k];
        k--;
    }

    printf("\nString invertida: %s", palavra2);

    //espaços
    for (i = 0; palavra[i]; i++) {
        if (palavra[i] == ' ')
            palavra3[i] = palavra[i + 1];
        //espaco++;
    }

    // printf("\nNumero de espacos: %i", espaco);
    printf("\nString sem espacos: %s", palavra3);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove all occurences of a character in C string - Example needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161822/remove-all-occurences-of-a-character-in-c-string-example-needed)

Comment: Curious, who or what text suggested using `scanf("%[^\n]", palavra);` vs. something like `fgets(palavra, sizeof palavra, stdin);`?

Comment: I tried both, got the same result. Im learning C in school, got it from a teacher's pdf.

Comment: Please write `int main` instead of `void main`. The latter is invalid since the ISO C90 standard, which was published in the year 1990.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the extra `;` at the end of `for (i = 0; palavra[i] != '\0'; i++);`

With the extraneous `;`, the loop is empty, the following code executes once with `i` equal to `strlen(palavra)`.

You can avoid this kind of silly bug by using the Kernighan and Ritchie indentation style: put the `{` at the end of the line with the `if`, `for`, `while`, `do` or `switch` statement. This makes it much less likely to type a spurious `;` between the control statement and its block.

To remove the spaces, use the 2 finger method:

```
//espaços
for (i = j = 0; palavra[i]; i++) {
    if (palavra[i] != ' ') {
        palavra3[j++] = palavra[i];
    }
}
palavra3[j] = '\0';  // set the null terminator
```

Comment: @chux: thanks for the edit, consistency is the golden rule indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Keep a counter of the new string length k ,check if a character is a space, if it is a space ignore it else increment k and add that character to new string.Example-

```
int k = 0;              //k will be the new string length after the loop
for (int i = 0; palavra[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (palavra[i] != ' ')
    {
        palavra3[k++] = palavra[i];
    }
}
palavra3[k] = '\0';
```

This example also works in the case of multiple consecutive spaces.